# MariaDB Stored Procedure store paramters for update

Tags: mariadb

I am trying to write a MariaDB stored procedure.

Due to SQL_SAFE_UPDATES, it is required to use the ID column to use in the WHERE clause for updates. Due to this, what is the normal approach to also select a value from one of the other columns? I do not want to have multiple SELECT statements as it seems inefficient and room for error because they could return values from different rows.

I would like to store my first select statement

```
 SELECT id, sequence FROM RECORDSEQUENCE WHERE SEQTABLE = SeqTable;
```

In the following two parameters @id, @seq from two seperate columns in the above query and use them in the UPDATE statement as well as the IF statement.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`sd`@`%` PROCEDURE `SD_GenerateNextRecordSequence`(IN SeqTable int)
BEGIN
     SELECT id, sequence FROM RECORDSEQUENCE WHERE SEQTABLE = SeqTable;
    IF (@seq IS NOT NULL) THEN
     SET @NEXTSEQ := @seq+1;
    UPDATE RECORDSEQUENCE SET RECORDSEQUENCE = @NEXTSEQ WHERE id = @id;
     ELSE
     SET @NEXTSEQ := 100;
     INSERT INTO RECORDSEQUENCE (RECORDSEQUENCE,SEQTABLE) VALUES (@NEXTSEQ,SeqTable);
     END IF;
SELECT @NEXTSEQ as SEQUENCE;
END
```

Comment: Check MySQL version by running `SELECT version();`.

Comment: Hi sorry as I should have mentioned I am using MariaDB at present. I believe it’s 10.6

Comment: If that's the case, you can generate sequence number using either [MariaDB sequence engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sequence-storage-engine/) or ["WITH RECURSIVE" common table expression](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/). Anyways, can you illustrate the table example before and after update? So that we can see what exactly you want to achieve. Thanks